# Как программно можно создать новую строку в таблице?

Tags: delphi, sql-server

Здравствуйте, подскажите как создать в Delphi новую строку (для БД MS SQL) при нажатии кнопки, в таблице (`Files`) с полями `id_file_vkr`, `file_vkr`, `Id_student`?

Comment: или TDataSet.Insert, если работаете через них

Answer (score 3):

Если программно, то значит [INSERT](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_operator_insert.html).

> Оператор INSERT вставляет новые записи в таблицу. При этом значения столбцов могут представлять собой литеральные константы, либо являться результатом выполнения подзапроса. Во втором случае будет вставлено столько строк, сколько возвращается подзапросом.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используйте ADO компоненты в делфи для работы с базами данных, то запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Files (id_file_vkr ,file_vkr, Id_student) VALUES (2,"file_vkr_text", 5)');
ADOQuery1.Active := True;
```

Если поля инкрементные некоторые у вас, то их вносить в базу не надо вручную, они автоматом приращение делают. С делфи давно уже не работаю, потому мог где-то ошибиться. P.S. Читайте документацию по делфи в связке с MSSQL.